# Devise Ajax 404 routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am testing ajax with devise and am running into this error in console:

```
GET https://example.com/users/get_company?foo=bar 404 (Not Found)
```

and rails server is returning:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):
```

A little bit of code:

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'account#show', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end    

get 'users/get_company', as: 'get_company'
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]
```

controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json
  def get_company
    @company = Company.first.name
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

In views/devise/registrations there is new.html.erb, get_company.js.coffee and in assets/javascripts there is get_company.js.coffee.
These seem to be working fine because the event happens and then I am getting the routing error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am just learning this to help out with a project. Please ask for any additional code or anything that might help explain the situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey your route of `get_company` is missing `/`, so it would be:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'account#show', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
  # 1: If you put your get_company route here, it still works
  get '/users/get_company' => 'registrations#get_company', as: 'get_company'
end    

# 2: If you put your get_company route here, it works as well
# get '/users/get_company' => 'registrations#get_company', as: 'get_company'
```

You code will work fine either you put the route in position `#1` or `#2`

Comment: thank you! For some reason position 2 didnt work and it came back with a message telling me to wrap it with a scope. So position 1 is what worked ... and the correct syntax of course.